# XFCE4 - Session and Startup: where are autostart items saved?

Tags: configuration, xfce, session, autostart

In XFCE4, there is a list of items to be started when an XFCE4-session is started
*(XFCE4 Settings `xfce4-settings-manager` → Tab "Application Autostart")*:
[image]

I'm wondering where this list is stored.

In `~/.config/autostart` I have three `.desktop` files, which are available in the aforementioned list, but there are many more items in that list than those three files.
I was wondering if those items are stored somewhere in a human readable file, or perhaps directory structure.
Although I'm not exactly planning to edit those items via scripting, it would help if it was at all possible to modify that list while a session is not active. For instance should I want to edit those items over SSH, while no one is logged in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The entries you see are populated from:

`~/.config/autostart` (user-specific)

and

`/etc/xdg/autostart/` (system-wide)

If you want to disable something from the second system-wide location, you create the appropriate entry to your start-up directory with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Hidden=true
```

E.g. I have `/etc/xdg/autostart/blueman.desktop` - to disable it you create:

`~/.config/autostart/blueman.desktop` with the above content.

Redefining something looks a tad tedious and over-complicated but you first have to disable it, then create your own desired entry.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it, the `Hidden=` option is essentially the checkmark in the list, which I might say is a little confusing but it works as you described. And `RunHook=` refers to the "Trigger" setting.